# Testing a variable against a set of other variables, one of which is NULL, returns false

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this:

```
DECLARE @First INT, @Second INT, @Third INT

SET @First = 1
SET @Second = 2
SET @Third = NULL -- just for clarity

IF(@First NOT IN (@Second, @Third))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Here' -- expected this line to print...
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'There' -- but this line prints instead.
    END
```

Why does it enter the "else" block?  If I try it this way, I get the expected results:

```
IF(@First IN (@First, @Second, @Third))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Here' -- this line prints, as expected.
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'There' 
    END
```

Why does a check to see if one value *DOES NOT* exist in a set of other values using `IN`, where one of those values is `NULL`, return false?

I'm sure someone is going to tell me that this is expected behavior for some esoteric, SQL-y reason, but I think we can all agree that this is a dangerous "default" likely to trip up the unwary.

Comment: It returns `unknown` not `false` per the title. SQL uses three valued logic.

Comment: Yep, I know that now based on the answers.  It's very hard to determine that, though.  I'm trying to figure out how to observe the value of `@First NOT IN (@Second, @Third)`.

Comment: `case when your_predicate then 'true' when not your_predicate then 'false' else 'unknown' end`

Comment: Sure, but what if I want to store the value of the predicate?  I know I can use case when, but ... that's the only way?

Comment: SQL server does not have a Boolean datatype. You can't assign the result of a predicate directly to a variable or column if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Logically, I would think the values would map to [BIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)

Comment: You can't do `if (cast 1 as bit)` either and treat bit as Boolean in that direction too. There is a SQL standard Boolean datatype but not implemented in SQL server currently.

Comment: Just like I said: esoteric :)  Thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: The [boolean data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) is documented with this caveat: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic example of `NOT IN` trap with `NULL` value. This is no esoteric just simple as:

```
@First IN (@Second, @Third)
<=>
@First = @Second OR @First = @Third
```

Now based on [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

```
@First NOT IN (@Second, @Third)
<=>  
@First <> @Second AND @First <> @Third

1 <> 2 AND            1 <> NULL => NULL
true AND NULL => NULL  -- go to the else branch
```

Mystery solved.

Comment: And null always fails to the "else" branch in an "if" block.

Comment: @roryap Yes, only true will get to IF branch, anything else go to `ELSE`. `NOT IN` is tricky and should always be used with `not nullable` values

Answer (score 2):

Instead reading `NULL` to mean, "Doesn't have a value", it's better in this situation to think of `NULL` as meaning, "It's not clear what the value is."

With that understanding of `NULL`, now when this expression compares `@First`  with each of the values in the sequence, we can't definitively say that `@First`'s value is not in the sequence, because it's unclear what the value of `@Third` will be.

The second code sample works because you can definitively say that `@First` does exist in the sequence.